# Pivot Cache in one one workbook, Pivot table in another workbook

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

I have created a Pivot Cache in (say)Workbook 'sourceBook.xlsx' in sheet 'sourceSheet'. I am trying to create a Pivot table in a different workbook 'destinBook.xlsx' in sheet 'destinSheet'.

```
Dim pCache As PivotCache
Dim pTable As PivotTable
Dim pRange As Range

Module2.hc_book.Activate
Set pRange = ActiveSheet.Range(hc_pidCol & "1:" & hc_pidCol & hc_lastRow)

Set pCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, pRange)
Module2.mt_book.Activate
Set tempSheet = Worksheets.Add
tempSheet.Select
Set pTable = ActiveSheet.PivotTables.Add(pCache, Range("A1"), "MyPivotTable")
```

The code is giving me error in the last line - "Invalid procedure call or argument", where I am setting the pTable. The code works fine for destination in the same sheet. So, please let me know where I am making the mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `PivotCache` is the memory cache for a `PivotTable` report. This memory cache is needed for the `PivotTable` to function in the first place.

You could create a `PivotCache` from data in the current workbook, but it would have to be part of the PivotCaches in the new workbook, in order to create a PivotTable based of off it.

Since the PivotCache is not available in the new `Workbook.PivotCaches`, you cannot create a PivotTable in that workbook of off it and that's why your code doesn't run.

This runs fine:

```
Sub test()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim pRange As Range
    Dim pc As PivotCache
    Dim pt As PivotTable

    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)

    Set pRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C3")

    Set pc = wb.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, pRange)
    Set pt = ws.PivotTables.Add(pc, Range("F2"), "MyPivotTable")

End Sub
```

This does not work:

```
Sub test()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim pRange as Range
    Dim pc As PivotCache
    Dim pt As PivotTable

    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)

    Set pRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C3")

    Set pc = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, pRange) 'Cache in ThisWorkbook
    Set pt = ws.PivotTables.Add(pc, Range("F2"), "MyPivotTable") 'Cache unavailable, error 5 - Invalid Procedure Call or Argument. 

End Sub
```

The invalid argument for this error is the `pc` object.

In short: `PivotCache` object needs to be part of the `PivotCaches` collection of the `Workbook` where you wish to create the `PivotTable`

**EDIT:** Just to clarify: A `PivotCache` is an in memory object. It has nothing to do with the source where you got the data from. This source can indeed be the range in your first workbook, or the results of a SQL query, or a CSV-file, whatever you choose.

**EDIT 2:** A very basic implementation of "copying" a pivotCache to a new workbook would be:

```
Sub CopyPivotCache()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim InitialPivotCache As PivotCache
    Dim CopyPivotCache As PivotCache

    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    Set InitialPivotCache = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches(1)
    Set CopyPivotCache = wb.PivotCaches.Create(InitialPivotCache.SourceType, InitialPivotCache.SourceData)
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice detailed explanation :)

Comment: @ShaiRado Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @ShaiRado, for the time being, I am creating the Pivot table in the same Workbook, and using Lookup to get the values I need. However I would like to know if we can copy the PivotCache of first workbook to the 2nd workbook, so as to create a Pivot table in the new workbook.

Comment: @Vikash See Edit 2: The most basic way to copy the initial PivotCache to the second Workbook.