# Create a pivot table in a new workbook from data in another workbook

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I want to create a pivot table in a new workbook from data selected in another workbook.

I have tried the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44644002/pivot-cache-in-one-one-workbook-pivot-table-in-another-workbook/50715949) but I get a reference error "1004" in the last line of code.

```
Sub test()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim pRange As Range
    Dim pc As PivotCache
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim InitialPivotCache As PivotCache
    Dim CopyPivotCache As PivotCache


    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)

    Set pRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:B6")

    Set pc = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, pRange) 'Cache in ThisWorkbook

    Call CountCaches

    Set CopyPivotCache = wb.PivotCaches.Create(pc.SourceType, pc.SourceData)
    Set pt = ws.PivotTables.Add(CopyPivotCache, Range("A3"), "MyPivotTable") 

End Sub
```

I Counted number of caches with this code in my thisworkbook after I have set the "pc" cache I found 0 caches.

```
Sub CountCaches()
  MsgBox "There are " _
      & ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Count _
      & " pivot caches in the active workook."
End Sub
```

I don't know what's wrong in my code. How can I fix it?

Comment: A quick question - why are you creating a pivot table in a seperate workbook? If anything, that should be a normal table. Pivot tables are supposed to be directly referring to an internal data source

Comment: I want my user to select data file (worksheet) and do all my calculation  in another workbook. It's more clean.

Comment: I can tell you from my personal coding experience, that it's not "more clean". If anything, you are going to cause interconnectivity issues doing this. If you need to showcase data for some basic user editing a simple table (`ListObject`) will do.

Comment: I want to use pivot table just to make a groupby name list in my rows and then sum values in another column. Is there another way to do it fast without pivot tables?

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub CreatePT()

Set wb = Workbooks.Add 'Create new workbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
pRange = "[" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "]" & Sheet15.Name & "!" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(15).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, SourceData:=pRange). _
    CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="[" & wb.Name & "]" & ws.Name & "!R1C1", TableName:="PivotTable4"

End Sub
```